# How can airflow dag pick up config json from local directory?

Tags: json, airflow

I am running my airflow dags with config jsons provided in 
Admin->Variables section and using the line 
`dag_config = Variable.get("conig_version_1", deserialize_json=True)`. The same json is residing in /airflow/configs/ directory. What needs to be modified in dag_file.py so that it picks file from local directory?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow variables are stored in Database. If you have a JSON file that you want to import then Go to **Airflow** -> **Variables**. Click on **Choose File** and click on Import.

You can also use cli command:

```
airflow variables -i /path/to/var.json
```

Comment: can you explain how to use above command while triggering a job like this
`airflow trigger_dag my_dag` and in dag file how can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import json
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable
env = os.environ.get('ENV')
if env=='DEV-LOCAL':
    Variable=json.loads(r'c:\temp\variables.json')
```

This works well for me.  you'll need to export the variable.json from the airflow UI first and save it to your local.